# How to get the count of users within the last hour in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the number of customers within the last hour but when I run the code,
it returns an empty array (I have already checked that there are some data in `updated` within the last hour).

Here is the code.

```
const start = new Date();
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //milliseconds 00:00:00.000
const end = new Date();
end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); //milliseconds 23:59:59.999

const now = new Date().getTime();
const lastOneHr = new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000;

//get chart info
router.post("/getcustomerchart/:adminId", (req, res, next) => {
  const adminId = req.params.adminId;
  Customer.aggregate([
    {
      $facet: {
        today: [
          {
            $match: {
              $and: [
                { adminId: adminId },
                { updated: { $gte: start, $lte: end } },
              ],
            },
          },
          { $count: "count" },
        ],
        lastHour: [
          {
            $match: {
              $and: [
                { adminId: adminId },
                { updated: { $gte: lastOneHr, $lte: now } },
              ],
            },
          },
          { $count: "count" },
        ],
        all: [{ $match: { adminId: adminId } }, { $count: "count" }],
      },
    },
  ])
    .then((docs) => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        customer_info: docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            lastHour: doc.lastHour,
            today: doc.today,
            all: doc.all,
          };
        }),
      };
      res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

Here's the result from Postman. I managed to get the count for `today` and `all` except for the `lastHour`. Is there something wrong with the format?

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "customer_info": [
        {
            "lastHour": [],
            "today": [
                {
                    "count": 1
                }
            ],
            "all": [
                {
                    "count": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, are you confident there is data from the past one hour? because there is only 1 for today. What you saw might have been from other `adminId`?

Comment: @thammada Just to be sure, I added 2 data just now using the same adminId. However, I think it might be because of the date format. Currently it's 1.15 am , 17th June 2020 here in Japan but when I run the query again in Postman, the today count is 1 even though it's supposed to be 2 and lastHour still return an empty array.

Comment: How did you add the data, it could be because of how you insert your data, not how you query it

Comment: @thammada I added them through a React form which connects to Mongo Atlas. I also confirmed that the data reflected in the database. I also can check all submitted data in a table component in React. The date in the table (Material UI Table npm) is correctly displayed as 1.23 am (June 17th) but the format in Mongo Atlas is 2020-06-16T16:11:23.067+00:00. How do I change the format then?

Comment: @thammada but getTime() is already in milliseconds no?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you are right. Are you storing your date as a `Date` type?

Comment: @thammada Yes. Here's the schema/model in Mongoose for updated. updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216075/discussion-between-thammada-and-danial-asraf-norbee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your time to a `Date` object, MongoDB can not compare it with timestamp

So this will work

```
const now = new Date();
const lastOneHr = new Date(now.getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000);
```